# Loop xml and persist to database java

Tags: java, xml, rest, parsing

I'm trying to loop through xml and extract values and persist it to mysql using rest . this is what i have so far.But its only extracting the first string that has value songIts adding to the database but id like to add two at a time.

```
    NodeList artistList = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/plist/dict/dict/dict/string[@rollno='artist']", root, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < artistList.getLength(); ++i) {
            Element e = (Element) artistList.item(i);
            artist= e.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();


            book.setIsbn(artist);
            book.setName(song);



            returnCode = "200";
            em = Resource.getEntityManager();
        }
```

This is the xml which i'm trying to parse using xpath i'd like to extract all rollno="song" and persist them one after the other ,any advice or help will mean a lot .Thanks

```
  <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
      <key>Major Version</key>
      <integer>1</integer>
      <key>Application Version</key>
      <string>7.0.2</string>
      <key>Show Content Ratings</key>
      <true />
      <key>Tracks</key>
      <dict>
         <key>1288</key>
         <dict >
            <key>Track ID</key>
            <integer>1288</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string rollno="song">Brighter Than Sush</string>
            <key>Artist</key>
            <string rollno="artist">Aqualug</string>
            <key>Album Artist</key>
            <string>Aqualung</string>
            <key>Album</key>
            <key>Track ID</key>
            <integer>1288</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string rollno="song">james</string>
            <key>Artist</key>
            <string rollno="artist">martha</string>
            <key>Album Artist</key>
            <string>Aqualung</string>
            <key>Album</key>
         </dict>


      </dict>
   </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: so you are only getting Aqualug?

Comment: @abtpst exactly and i'd like to get aqualug and james..

Comment: well your xpath seems to be correct. are you sure you are only getting 1 value in the list? have you tried printing out the artist in the loop?

Comment: and dont you mean Aqualug and martha?

Comment: by the way, which java library are you using for parsing the XML?

Comment: i havent printed out the artist in a loop ,i'm using xpath   to parse it .and yes martha sorry

Comment: try printing out the artist value. this way we can confirm whether your xpath is being properly parsed. are you using apache tika to parse the xml?

Comment: i got this  output [Aqualung][Aqualung, martha]

Comment: I'm using a regular parse  method

Comment: is that what you get when you do for (int i = 0; i < artistList.getLength(); ++i) {
            Element e = (Element) artistList.item(i);
            artist= e.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            System.out.println(artist);

            book.setIsbn(artist);
            book.setName(song);



            returnCode = "200";
            em = Resource.getEntityManager();
        }

Comment: no thats what i get when i parse it in another .java application using the same method above but if i want to add to database only one of them goes in ?

Comment: hmm, so looks like you are parsing the xml correctly. must be the way you are passing the data to your other method

Comment: what does the book object look like? are you able to add both the artist to the book object correctly?

Comment: this is how the book looks like  
 @Id
 @Column(name="artist")
 String name;
 @Column(name="isbn")
 String isbn;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath/NodeList code is correct. As you only got the last XML value,
either you are doing things *after* the for loop (unlikely), or you overwrite fields of the same object created once *before* the loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < artistList.getLength(); ++i) {
        Element e = (Element) artistList.item(i);
        artist= e.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

        book = new Book(); // A new object here
        book.setIsbn(artist);
        book.setName(song);
        ... // Process book
    }
```

For good order you might prefer to use `e.getTextContent()`.